# Same code but different results, how is it possible?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have wrote matlab's code to python code, but it gives different "best_fitness" value, how is this possible? I want to write this matlab code to python, is it wrong method? Should i implement different method? matlabs best_fitness value is= 340, pytons best_fitness value= 17 ? how is this possible?
Here is python version.

```
import numpy as np
coord=[]
coord = np.array([[11, 47, 62],       
       [31, 37, 69],
       [32, 38, 46],
       [33, 46, 10],
       [34, 61, 33],
       [35, 62, 63],
       [36, 63, 69],
       [37, 32, 22],
       [38, 45, 35],
       [39, 59, 15],
       [40, 5, 6],
       [41, 10, 17],
       [42, 21, 10],
       [43, 5, 64],
       [44, 30, 15],
       [45, 39, 10],
       [46, 32, 39],
       [47, 25, 32],
       [48, 25, 55],
       [49, 48, 28],
       [50, 56, 37],
       [61, 40, 50]],dtype=np.int)
city=len(coord)
best_solution=[]
best_fitness=100000000
pop_size=1000  
CR=0.8 # %YÜZDE 90 OLASILIKLA CAPRAZLANIYOR.
MR=0.5
MaxIter=5000



# distance = np.zeros((coord.shape[0], coord.shape[0]))
distance = np.zeros([city,city])

for i in range(city):
    for j in range(city):
        distance[i][j] = np.sqrt((coord[i][1] - coord[j][1]) ** 2 + (coord[i][2] - coord[j][2]) ** 2)

population=np.zeros([pop_size,city],dtype=np.int)     
for i in range(pop_size):
    population[i][:]=np.random.permutation(city)

fitness=np.zeros([1,pop_size])   

for i in range(pop_size):
             fitness[0][i]=0
             for j in range(city-1):
                 # fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+distance[[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]]
                 fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]
                 fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][city-1]][population[i][1]]
                 if best_fitness > fitness[0][i]: 
                     best_solution=population[i][:]
                     best_fitness=fitness[0][i] 




b=np.min(fitness) # there is no lower than this value but it gives 13 or 20.
```

here is matlab version.

```
clc 
clear
coord=[11 47 62;
       31 37 69;
       32 38 46;
       33 46 10;
       34 61 33;
       35 62 63;
       36 63 69;
       37 32 22;
       38 45 35;
       39 59 15;
       40 5 6;
       41 10 17;
       42 21 10;
       43 5 64;
       44 30 15;
       45 39 10;
       46 32 39;
       47 25 32;
       48 25 55;
       49 48 28;
       50 56 37;
       61 40 50];

  [city,~]=size(coord);

     best_solution=[];

   best_fitness=100000000;
 pop_size=1000;  
  CR=0.8; %YÜZDE 90 OLASILIKLA CAPRAZLANIYOR.
 MR=0.5;

  MaxIter=5000;

 %51x51 matriste her şehirden şehire uzaklıgı bul  
   distance=[];
   for i=1:city
       for j=1:city
           distance(i,j)=sqrt((coord(i,2)-coord(j,2))^2+(coord(i,3)-coord(j,3))^2);
       end
   end
   %rastgele 100 tane cozum olusturdu.
   population=[];
for i=1:pop_size
    population(i,:)=randperm(city);
end
 %population


 for i=1:pop_size
    fitness(i)=0; %başta bos olusturuyor dikkat.
    for j=1:city-1
        %dk 32:48
        %mesela 14 ile 22. sutunun arasındaki mesafe 
        %j+1 var diye city -1 yazdık.
        %sırayla 2 sehir arasındaki mesafe hesaplanıyor.

        fitness(i)=fitness(i)+distance(population(i,j),population(i,j+1));
    end
    %son sehirden bastaki sehire donme icin.
    fitness(i)=fitness(i)+distance(population(i,city),population(i,1));
    if  best_fitness>fitness(i)  %fitness(i)<best_fitness
        best_solution=population(i,:);
        best_fitness=fitness(i);
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best fitness is going to change in every iteration due to the random generation involved (randperm and np.random.permutation). But you are right that the Python script generates numbers around 10-20 whilst Matlab is in the hundreds.

in your python script your are calling:

`fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]
fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][city-1]][population[i][1]]`

in the same for loop, this doesnt happen in the Matlab script, remove an indentation in the python script like the following:

```
import numpy as np
coord=[]
coord = np.array([[11, 47, 62],       
       [31, 37, 69],
       [32, 38, 46],
       [33, 46, 10],
       [34, 61, 33],
       [35, 62, 63],
       [36, 63, 69],
       [37, 32, 22],
       [38, 45, 35],
       [39, 59, 15],
       [40, 5, 6],
       [41, 10, 17],
       [42, 21, 10],
       [43, 5, 64],
       [44, 30, 15],
       [45, 39, 10],
       [46, 32, 39],
       [47, 25, 32],
       [48, 25, 55],
       [49, 48, 28],
       [50, 56, 37],
       [61, 40, 50]],dtype=np.int)
city=len(coord)
best_solution=[]
best_fitness=100000000
pop_size=1000  
CR=0.8 # %YÜZDE 90 OLASILIKLA CAPRAZLANIYOR.
MR=0.5
MaxIter=5000



# distance = np.zeros((coord.shape[0], coord.shape[0]))
distance = np.zeros([city,city])

for i in range(city):
    for j in range(city):
        distance[i][j] = np.sqrt((coord[i][1] - coord[j][1]) ** 2 + (coord[i][2] - coord[j][2]) ** 2)
#print(distance)
population=np.zeros([pop_size,city],dtype=np.int)     
for i in range(pop_size):
    population[i][:]=np.random.permutation(city)

fitness=np.zeros([1,pop_size])   

for i in range(pop_size):
    fitness[0][i]=0
    for j in range(city-1):
        # fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+distance[[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]]
        fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]]
    fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][city-1]][population[i][1]]
    if best_fitness > fitness[0][i]: 
        best_solution=population[i][:]
        best_fitness=fitness[0][i] 

b=np.min(fitness) # there is no lower than this value but it gives 13 or 20.
```

Comment: but this line "fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][city-1]][population[i][1]]" should in "i" loop. is it in i loop? in spider program, its looks like out of "i" loop.

Comment: I'm running the script in a python interpreter through command prompt, in the example above: fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][city-1]][population[i][1]] is in the i for loop, fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][j]][population[i][j+1]] is in the j for loop.

Comment: my second question is: i know matlabs and pythons, 0-1 index. but i didnt use "-1" in python, except last "fitness " equation. why i had to use "city-1"??? and why there is no any "-1" in other codes.

Comment: also first equation that without city-1 is in i and j loop . secont fitness func. is in only i loop in matlab.

Comment: You have the city-1 in both matlab and python scripts for the j for loop, this is because you are calling for population[j+1] which is one above the limit of length for city. Remember to upvote any comments or answers if they were useful :)

Comment: no, there is no city-1 in matlab.  fitness(i)=fitness(i)+distance(population(i,city),population(i,1))

Comment: In the Matlab script we find: 
    for j=1:city-1

Comment: the city-1 in fitness[0][i]=fitness[0][i]+ distance[population[i][city-1]][population[i][1]] is needed because python lists start at 0 where as Matlab starts at 1.

Comment: yes but in matlab only 1 times in for loop definition, in python, in loop definition and last function. there is difference.  2 times in python and 1 times in matlab.

Comment: in both cases city is the same size of 22, you are assigning to the last element in the array each time for both lists where python you need to call 21 for the 22nd element in a list so in python you need [city-1] where matlab only needs [city] to get to the last element.

Comment: as an extra bit that might make more sense, when you call range in python the first number in the for loop is 0 not 1 like matlab, hence the i and j dont need any -1 adding tot he script. if you call for i in range(22): print(i) you will get an output from 0-21.